# How to trim and reshape dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have df that looks like this:

```
a b  c d e f 
1 na 2 3 4 5
1 na 2 3 4 5
1 na 2 3 4 5
1 6 2 3 4 5
```

How do I trim and reshape the dataframe so that for every column the n/a are dropped and the dataframe looks like this:

Edit;

`df.dropna()` is dropping all the rows.

```
a b  c d e f 
1 6 2 3 4 5
```

This dataframe has millions of rows, I need to be able to drop the n/a rows by column while retaining rows and columns with data in them.

edit;

`df.dropna()` is dropping all the rows in the column. When I check if the columns with n/a are empty, `df.column_name.empty()` I get false. So there is data in columns with n/a

Comment: Do you think `df = df.dropna()` ?

Comment: just made a edit. df.dropna() is dropping all the rows. When I check the columns that show n/a to see if they are all the way empty, they are not.

Comment: I test it nad it remove all rows without last, because no `NaN` there.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost, why `dropna` is not working?

Comment: @jezrael just discovered the issue I think, when I look through the columns it is not n/a it says 'None'. I think that is why when I did the .empty() check the result came back false, but df.dropna is considering 'None' as n/a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me `dropna` working nice for remove missing values and `None`s:

```
df = df.dropna()
print (df)
   a    b  c  d  e  f
3  1  6.0  2  3  4  5
```

But if possible multiple values for removing create mask by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), chain testing missing values with `isnull` and last filter by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) - return at least one `True` per row by inverted mask `~`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', None, 's', 'd'],
                   'b': ['na',7, 2, 6], 
                   'c': [2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'd': [3, 3, 3, 3],
                   'e': [4, 4, np.nan, 4], 
                   'f': [5, 5, 5, 5]})

print (df)
      a   b  c  d    e  f
0     a  na  2  3  4.0  5
1  None   7  2  3  4.0  5
2     s   2  2  3  NaN  5
3     d   6  2  3  4.0  5

df1 = df.dropna()
print (df1)
   a   b  c  d    e  f
0  a  na  2  3  4.0  5
3  d   6  2  3  4.0  5

mask = (df.isin(['na', 'n/a']) | df.isnull()).any(axis=1)

df2 = df[~mask]
print (df2)
   a  b  c  d    e  f
3  d  6  2  3  4.0  5
```